# How Can I Scrape Data From Websites Don't Return Simple HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have been using requests and BeautifulSoup for python to scrape html from basic websites, but most modern websites don't just deliver html as a result. I believe they run javascript or something (I'm not very familiar, sort of a noob here). I was wondering if anyone knows how to, say , search for a flight on google flights and scrape the top result aka the cheapest price??

If this were simple html, I could just parse the html tree and find the text result, but this does not appear when you view the "page source". If you inspect the element in your browser, you can see the price inside hmtl tags as if you were looking at the regular page source of a basic website.

What is going on here that the inspect element has the html but the page source doesn't? And does anyone know how to scrape this kind of data?

Thanks so much!

[image: Inspect Element]
[image: Javascript?]

Comment: Ok so I think I figured it out. When I was pulling the page source, I was doing it so quickly in that the page didn't have time to get the javascript response from server and deliver it back. As someone about mentioned. So I added a sleep timer in my script, even a delay of 1 second seemed to work. The no delay method returned no "real" html info, with the delay I get all the info I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're spot on -- the page markup is getting added with javascript after the initial server response. I haven't used BeautifulSoup, but from its documentation, it looks like it doesn't execute javascript, so you're out of luck on that front.

You might try [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), which is basically a virtual browser -- people use it for front-end testing. It executes javascript, so it might be able to give you what you want.

But if you're specifically looking for Google Flights information, there's an API for that :) https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/

Comment: So is there a way that you know of getting that javascript-loaded, secondary response html in selenium? And yes there is an api but you have to pay : /. I'm just tinkering trying to learn.

Thanks for the response

Comment: Ok so I think I figured it out. When I was pulling the page source, I was doing it so quickly in that the page didn't have time to get the javascript response from server and deliver it back.  So I added a sleep timer in my script, even a delay of 1 second seemed to work. The no delay method returned no "real" html info, with the delay I get all the info I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [`Scrapy`](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/), which will allow you to scrape a page, along with a lot of other spider functionality. Scrapy has a great integration with [`Splash`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash), which is a library you can use to execute the javascript in a page. Splash can be used stand-alone, or you can get the [`Scrapy-Splash`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash).

Note that Splash essentially runs it's own server to do the javascript execution, so it's something that would run alongside your main script and would be called. Scrapy manages this via 'middleware', or a set processes that run on every request: in your case you would fetch the page, run the Javascript in Splash, and then parse the results.

This may be a slightly lighter-weight option than plugging into Selenium or the like, especially if all you're trying to do is render the page rather than render it and then interact with various parts in an automated fashion.