# Why is beautiful soup parsing different html than the source? Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been trying to create a script that parses Instagram usernames to tell me whether some are available. Originally I was using a status code check but it turns out Instagram doesn't actually use a code 404 on it's empty pages, and still returns 200. So I then imported beautiful soup to try and parse the html for the page title text, but for whatever reason, the html being parsed looks very different from the actual page, and lacks the title text as well as many other elements entirely. I'm also pretty certain all my logic at the bottom might be wrong.

So this is my code, sorry if it is horrible I'm new

```
`
#random word selector stuff
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text
words = text.split()
rng = randint(0,len(words))

#random proxy selector stuff
ipreq = requests.get(url2)
nums = ipreq.text
ips = nums.split()
randomcheck = randint(0,len(ips))

#this one worked 103.149.130.38:80
proxies  = {
'http': 'http://' + '103.149.130.38:80',
'https': 'https://' + ips\[randomcheck\],
}

print(proxies)

while True:
user = ""

for words[rng] in random.choices(words):
        user = user + words[rng]

response = requests.get("http://www.instagram.com/{user}/",proxies=proxies,headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}, timeout=100)

ref = requests.get("http://www.instagram.com/{user}/")
ref.text
src = 'Page not found • Instagram'
soup = BeautifulSoup(ref.text, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())

if (soup.find_all(response) == src):
    
    print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + f"NOT FOUND: {user}" + Fore.RESET) 
    
elif (soup.find_all(response) != src):
    print(Fore.GREEN + f"USER FOUND: {user}" + Fore.RESET)

else:
    print("BLOCKED FROM INSTAGRAM")
    time.sleep(15)
```

`
I think most of the issue is happening in this block

```
`response = requests.get("http://www.instagram.com/%7Buser%7D/",proxies=proxies,headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}, timeout=100)

ref = requests.get("http://www.instagram.com/{user}/")
ref.text
src = 'Page not found • Instagram'
soup = BeautifulSoup(ref.text, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

`
And I think that last bit of logic probably needs fixing, but at the moment I think the main issue is the seemingly incorrect or incomplete parsing

For proper urls and stuff to try the code here's a pastebin it thought this post was spam
https://pastebin.com/BStK839i

Comment: looks like there are scripts running on that page, requests does not actually run the js scripts on the page, so none of that content gets to bs. you will need to use something like selenium which will load and run the scripts

Comment: Beautifulsoup is not the issue, as @Nullman said.  The issue is that `requests` fetches only the raw page content, without processing any javascript, so that's what beautifulsoup sees.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I Scrape Data From Websites Don't Return Simple HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668384/how-can-i-scrape-data-from-websites-dont-return-simple-html)

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out, it didn't require selenium, or even beautiful soup in the end. I ended up using insomnia to pull a specific request from Instagram and used that to check for active accounts. Works fairly reliably.

With this, the code can properly detect a 404 from a specific request rather than the full webpage.
Here is how the request works now
import time
from random import randint
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
# Takes one argument (a list) and returns  a random entry from the list
def get_word(theList):
    word = theList[randint(0, len(words))]
    return word

library_url = 

"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt"
r = requests.get(library_url)
text = r.text
words = text.split()




x = 0
while x < 20:       # set number of 
usernames to pull here
    user = get_word(words)
    url = 


'https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info'

    querystring = {"username": user}

    payload = ""
    headers = {
    "cookie": "csrftoken=LtAI7nLEUmwQBVHm8RgdCRMQ16intjoW",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "X-CSRFToken": "LtAI7nLEUmwQBVHm8RgdCRMQ16intjoW",
    "X-IG-App-ID": "936619743392459",
    "X-ASBD-ID": "198387",
    "X-IG-WWW-Claim": "hmac.AR33CwCq2HQ_1WEcNOsHCP82MAfJ7jz-X4ZkQjmNfLdqbUzl",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": 
"https://www.instagram.com/" + user + "/",
    "Cookie": "ig_did=E2C6F01C-8175-4845-9611-9574639967CD; datr=zWjIY8mPJR69mBaMTfC6F76S; mid=Y8hozgALAAEyUIhNqdosLFkRLTFx; ig_nrcb=1; sessionid=6376909533^%^3AIWhRZ5RduYODIO^%^3A17^%^3AAYet3kgHa2BvYzxaA4fcAd9tKqSZboHbypHoCmtsGQ; fbm_124024574287414=base_domain=.instagram.com; ds_user_id=6376909533; csrftoken=LtAI7nLEUmwQBVHm8RgdCRMQ16intjoW; shbid=17686\0546376909533\0541710534230:01f7037d9071f48e142111baad19e05a3ca054a556af4c5e0efde499d34e11ead8cfb6b2; shbts=1678998230\0546376909533\0541710534230:01f7fc81e993932a2ac0a4d6a4e677c9068aedd91aa3b88254d9eca8b84002ad7811ed7f; dpr=1.5; rur=EAG\0546376909533\0541710536554:01f7fd79b5b4ade965d6e703e258bd68be7feffa2a6d8f1cf5afae407c8af58218f19913; fbsr_124024574287414=aNHwq4XR6GFzI_1H2yt9uR9jXh4tPCED_i5jfH58DnE.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; fbsr_124024574287414=kpmzGJ-Q-v_gq-uEbKBQPnet57oErQMu7GWNPC7TQoM.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMTAwMDEyODE4MDgwODUwIiwiY29kZSI6IkFRQk02YmxlczlNU1JPMVU0UG5wQl83RlJqSlVKTllXUTJfRkhHWlkza2ZiMnBvbWpMRGY4czZxMjgzUE5WRlFDY0JuRUdfZUZRbU5zRUdGUGVrNHQwUmpSWWg1TkdlejA2ZVRUZ3h0RHRpdW5yY3Y1QUNmdnJuN0pfS0FuSDZONFNwRWJ4RnZqT3NTTDdzN3dacm1BQndSdy1HdWhUQXFLZjFrVnBHcXBoeFNZYnFnd1FIeUFQeHA4Sm5GMVVQNER4ZF84VWhBZFpOcThsamhYVTBFaVFyYXVWZ0U2MXhZLUt4Y2wzNDVvOTJvNHlzdjlyNlpKdFo4aW4ybVUxZzE3QXFkaVNKaXY0ME9DNk41LVVBZTJMWmoyX2dsTm9RZjZZVnpvNHpGU09kYW9KaGoxRFZrck0zSHNUOE1NSWxZSkFHdVdPYXR0b2tPellyTzhYay0zdkE1Iiwib2F1dGhfdG9rZW4iOiJFQUFCd3pMaXhuallCQU5TVG1yZDhSWkJ1RHJ0eUNoa0UwOGJsbmdmN1JZM25RU2FjaXl1c2hiZTFYMHdkQ1Bwc1Y0ZEdsNVQxWUV4VjJuUFRSZWRxUGNxblFaQ1Z3bUFXc0l6WE1lVEVUazU4WkFORGU2SUY2ZUVmc1NtZGRwaFpBTlFzZlpDQ2JGZTBDTXllQ05oQzNxWkNqYkNUZUpaQVA2dHI3RU9vS2hzQTFCUmduakV0aDdZVEJLS1A4d1NiYTVSYTVNUTVMOG8yZ1pEWkQiLCJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTY3OTAwMDQ0OH0",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "TE": "trailers"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

# doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')  this isn't needed anymore since this server responds with a 404 not found
if response.status_code == 404:
    print("User available: " + user)
else:
    print("User taken: " + user)
time.sleep(2.5)
x += 1
```

``
https://pastebin.com/mkkXjmR9